# Can't center this ul

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a menu and I can't center an ul inside second_nav. What's wrong with this menu?

This is my normal second nav

```
    /*second_nav*/
#second_nav{
    background: url("images/second_nav.png");
    height: 255px;
    width: 100%;
}
#second_nav ul{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0 170px;
    width: 654px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 25px 0 0 0;
}
#second_nav ul li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 60px; 
    height: 220px;

}
#second_nav ul li p{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #000000; 
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and this is my second_nav when screen is max- 820px i want to center this.

```
#second_nav{
        height: 255px;
        width:100%;.
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #second_nav ul{
        height: 215px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #second_nav ul li{
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #second_nav ul li img{
        width: 80%;
    }
```

Comment: wondering that,with `width:900%`, why would you wanna center it...????? :o .....still, try adding `margin:0 auto` and `text-align:center` in `#second_nav` and check if it works!

Comment: You should give the `<ul>` a width so it knows what to center with `margin:0 auto`

Comment: It was missclick but without this with I can't center it too

Comment: Still doesn't work with with

Answer (score 1):

Give `#second_nav ul` an explicit width. Without one, it's 100% of its parent (`#second_nav`), so there's no room either side to center it using `margin: auto`.

Try this:

```
#second_nav ul {
    height: 215px;
    width: 500px; /* or whatever you need... */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you only need to add the following rules

```
#second_nav ul {
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

look at **[this example](http://jsfiddle.net/DZ65F/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can check this:

```
   #second_nav{
            height: 255px;
            width:100%;  
            text-align:center;
        }
```

use `text-align: center;`
but ul need to be inline element "display:inline"

Answer (score 0):

1 thing that I didn't tell. This is my normal second nav

```
    /*second_nav*/
#second_nav{
    background: url("images/second_nav.png");
    height: 255px;
    width: 100%;
}
#second_nav ul{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0 170px;
    width: 654px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 25px 0 0 0;
}
#second_nav ul li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 60px; 
    height: 220px;

}
#second_nav ul li p{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #000000; 
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and this is my second_nav when screen is max- 820px i want to center this.

```
#second_nav{
        height: 255px;
        width:100%;.
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #second_nav ul{
        height: 215px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #second_nav ul li{
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #second_nav ul li img{
        width: 80%;
    }
```

Comment: You should update your question with this additional information instead of posting it as an answer :)